# Python script to script enter and exit

Tags: python

I am trying to create a python script that on a click of a button opens another python script and closes itself and some return function in the second script to return to the original script hope you can help.

Thanks.

Comment: You can't return to a program which you've closed. So, do you mean that the second script will re-launch the first one from scratch when it's done? Or that the first script will just close its window but keep running?

Comment: Also, which GUI library are you trying to use?

Answer (score 3):

Since your question is very vague, here's a somewhat vague answer:

First, think about whether you really need to do this at all. Why can't the first script just `import` the second script as a module and call some function on it?

But let's assume you've got a good answer for that, and you really do need to "close" and run the other script, where by "close" you mean "make your GUI invisible".

```
def handle_button_click(button):
    button.parent_window().hide()
    subprocess.call([sys.executable, '/path/to/other/script.py'])
    button.parent_window().show()
```

This will hide the window, run the other script, then show the window again when the other script is finished. It's generally a very bad idea to do something slow and blocking in the middle of an event handler, but in this case, because we're hiding our whole UI anyway, you can get away with it.

A smarter solution would involve some kind of signal that either the second script sends, or that a watcher thread sends. For example:

```
def run_other_script_with_gui_hidden(window):
    gui_library.do_on_main_thread(window.hide)
    subprocess.call([sys.executable, '/path/to/other/script.py'])
    gui_library.do_on_main_thread(window.show)

def handle_button_click(button):
    t = threading.Thread(target=run_other_script_with_gui_hidden)
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()
```

Obviously you have to replace things like `button.window()`, `window.hide()`, `gui_library.do_on_main_thread`, etc. with the appropriate code for your chosen window library.

If you'd prefer to have the first script actually exit, and the second script re-launch it, you *can* do that, but it's tricky. You don't want to launch the second script as a child process, but as a sibling. Ideally, you want it to just take over your own process. Except that you need to shut down your GUI before doing that, unless your OS will do that automatically (basically, Windows will, Unix will not). Look at the [`os.exec`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.execl) family, but you'll really need to understand how these things work in Unix to do it right. Unless you want the two scripts to be tightly coupled together, you probably want to pass the second script, on the command line, the exact right arguments to re-launch the first one (basically, pass it your whole `sys.argv` after any other parameters).

As an alternative, you can use [`execfile`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#execfile) to run the second script within your existing interpreter instance, and then have the second script `execfile` you back. This has similar, but not identical, issues to the `exec` solution.

Comment: Hi thanks do much for the reply. Well the idea is that the main python script has a growing list or paths to other python scripts. Kind of like a menu. When the user clicks for example the fifth button python5.py is started closing the main.py script. Then when the python5.py finishes maybe a function in python5.py closes python5.py and opens main.py. This would be suitable solution maybe you could help. Your first example with the hide window is really interesting but the things is how about when you have many python scripts that need to be opened and closed. Thanks.

Comment: You really need to decide what you mean by "close" before you can go any further. Does the script really need to stop running? Or close its main window? Or just hide it? Why does it need _any_ of that? Ever since Switcher or Multifinder in the late 80s, it's been pretty normal for launcher/menu apps to stay running; whatever GUI they have is in the background, so it's not a problem. And this means you can choose between allowing or denying the running of multiple scripts at the same time, just by controlling the state of the buttons. What about that design seems wrong to you?

Comment: Thank you for all the assistance. This has lead me in the right direction.